# How can I get results for a dimension (custom variables), where the value is not set or null or empty in GA4 google analytics?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

The GA4 removes such rows in which any of my other dimension is null along with custom dimension. I need to have such rows or else it will be just data loss.
Here is just sample of my code.

```
request = RunReportRequest(
            property=f"properties/{self.property_id}",
            dimensions=dimension_list,
            metrics=metrics_list,
            limit=row_limit,
            return_property_quota=quota_usage,
            date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2022-09-27", end_date="2022-10-06")],
            dimension_filter=FilterExpression(
                filter=Filter(
                                        field_name="customEvent:order_id",
                                        string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(value="8723903"),
                                    )
                                ),
keep_empty_rows = True,
            ignore_unknown_fields = True
        )
```

Comment: According to Google Analytics Documentation (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en&ref_topic=11151952)You you will see a value of (not set) for a custom dimension in the first 48 hours. However if you are getting null or even empty, you "ARE" sending empty or null to datalayer. Share your html part please so we can be more helpful.

Comment: I'll connect with my team and get back to you on this.